# Why are my file names hashed when I access them from my Google Drive Files on text editors?

Tags: google-drive, filename

When I try accessing my Google Drive folder on VS Code, the file names seem to be hashed and do not appear by their name. This is very annoying. I have tried different editors as well.

I have tried atom, pycharm, and sublime text. The only one that seems to work is Notepad++. I really want to avoid using Notepad, so are there any solutions to this?

I have been experiencing this for a long time. I love Ubuntu, I don't want to not use it because of one issue. Help is very much appreciated.

The code appears just fine as you can see in the second photo. It's only the file name that is the problem.

VS Code

[image: screenshot 1]

Atom

[image: screenshot 2]

Sublime Text

[image: screenshot 3]

Comment: As much as I like in general Google products, I deem unacceptable their refusal to deliver an official Linux Drive client.  https://abevoelker.github.io/how-long-since-google-said-a-google-drive-linux-client-is-coming/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the discussion on this topic by the Gnome developers at https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gvfs/-/issues/402.

Summary: The "hash" is the real name of the file. The original name (Display Name) is stored in metadata. It's not a bug in your editor; it's the way Google decided their system should work.

"Fixing" it involves hiding the real name of file, which risks confusing users and possible data loss. The Gnome developers chose to not dive into that no-win situation.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. So, there's not way to "Fix" it ? :(

Comment: What about this patch? https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/glib/-/commit/c597b0e552963a1331feb16c23e5a0d1698a338f

Answer (score 0):

Long time issue apparently.

Time and time again I fall back to this question and always forget the answer, when I solve it, I forget to add a comment here. This time though, hopefully it helps everyone.

My problem is not with VS Code but with Obsidian. Using the default `gio` sync gives and opening vault's folder show file names and dir with the same hashed names.

The solution form ewas going to something very different. Instead of gio, I've set up [googledrive-ocamlfuse](https://github.com/astrada/google-drive-ocamlfuse). There is some CLI involved and likely a call on boot that needs to be added so the folder is always there, but at least I can easily open the folder on Obsidian without any issues.