# Matlab file & folder names in hashcode in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: matlab, google-drive

I Install ubuntu 18.04 and setup matlab R2018a

I installed Google back up and sync on ubuntu 18.04, but when I open matlab and goto backup files on the folder.The name of the files and folders are show as hashcode  as in figure.Do you have any idea to change back to normal name (when I ceate a folder as Matlab ,its name look like hashcode).How to see normal names of those files and folders.Thank you in advance.

Names of files and folders like hash codes:

[image: Names of files and folders like hash codes]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are my file names hashed when I access them from my Google Drive Files on text editors?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1355619/why-are-my-file-names-hashed-when-i-access-them-from-my-google-drive-files-on-te)

Comment: Thank you very much...but no solution there...